# Spotipy can't authenticate on Azure Functions (OAuth)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, spotipy

I made a script that works perfectly when it runs locally but isn't able to authenticate in my Azure Functions app. At first, I thought it was because it couldn't read the .cache file.

After looking at the logs it's because it can't open a browser window to create the authentication token. I'm fairly new to Azure functions so I'm not sure how I can enable opening a browser if that's even possible.

I looked into the oauth2.py file in spotipy and found it's optional to open the browser but instead, the console asks for the redirected URL. Is there a way for me to get the redirected URL and enter it into the console instead?

Here's my code:

```
def create_playlist(cred):
    """Creates the playlist for Discover weekly to be copied to"""
    # Gain authorization to create playlist
    logging.info('Authenticating spotify secrets to create new playlist...')
    # spotipy.CacheFileHandler(cache_path='')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=cred[0],
                                                   client_secret=cred[1],
                                                   redirect_uri=cred[2],
                                                   scope='playlist-modify-private',
                                                   open_browser=False,
                                                   ))
    # Get returned list from get_playlist_info function
    logging.info('Determining playlist descriptors...')
    info = get_playlist_info()

    # New playlist for Discover Weekly
    logging.info('Creating new playlist...')
    new_playlist = sp.user_playlist_create(user=cred[4],
                                           name=info[0],
                                           public=False,
                                           collaborative=False,
                                           description=info[1])
    logging.info('Returning new playlist.')
    return new_playlist
```

Answer (score 0):

In Redirect URIs you enters one or more addresses which you want to whitelist with Spotify. And this URI enables the Spotify authentication service to automatically re-launch your app every time the user logs in.

You can set your Redirect URL by navigating to your Spotify developer dashboard and open the project you are working on. Then click "edit settings" and look for the redirect URIs field and put your redirect URI in the field and lastly save it.

> The **Authorization Code Flow** needs you to add a **redirect URI** to your application at **My Dashboard**. The `redirect_uri` argument or `SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI` environment variable must match the redirect URI added to your application in your Dashboard.

Following are some examples that you can use as redirect URIs.

`http://example.com`, `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1:9090`

The correct way in which you should authenticate yourself is shown in the code snippet below.

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(
        username=USERNAME,
        scope=SCOPE,
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
```

You should also export your redirect_uri, client ID, and secret before running your script and trying to authenticate. If you don't pass the values directly to the util.prompt_for_user_token function, it will read them from the environment.

Try running these in your terminal before running your script.

`export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID="YOUR CLIENT ID"`
`export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET="YOUR CLIENT SECRET"`
`export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost/'`

For more information you can read this [Authorization Code Flow](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#authorization-code-flow) document for Spotipy.

Comment: Authentication locally is not a problem. All of the parameters are configured and accessible. The issue arises with authentication on Azure Functions because a browser needs to be opened but isn't possible (or at least I don't think it is). So, I'm trying to determine if it's possible to open the URL without opening a browser, maybe using curl or something